# CKEditor - Custom word or phrase insertion function

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) so the user can easily enter texts. He also has to enter variables/tags that will be filled by the system afterwards like `{foo}`. To prevent error reports caused by minor typos I want to provide a dropdown list to insert those in the text. How can I achieve this?

I found a promising Plugin named [StrInsert](http://ckeditor.com/addon/strinsert) but it's not supported by newer CKEditor versions doess nor does it look well maintained. Any other known plugins?

Comment: You need a richer version of the official [placeholder](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/placeholder.html) plugin. I don't know about such plugin, so I think it will be easiest to write one. See the code of that plugin and code of some plugin which adds a drop down (like the [language](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/tree/master/plugins/language) plugin) and you should not have problems in building your own.

Comment: @Reinmar Thank you for the tip, I have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the placeholder plugin as [described here](https://zolson.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/ckeditor-placeholder-select/). I just use the placeholder format `[[foo]]` instead or the original one. If you are using the nuget package like me you have to download the following plugins and copy them into the plugins folder: `placeholder`, `widget` and `lineutils`. The add the plugin to your CKEditor config: `extraPlugins: 'placeholder'`

Edit1:
You can also use [this custom plugin](https://github.com/Limantara/DropdownPlaceholder)